# What does "tippy top" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

> And except for those at the tippy top, shareholder value isn’t a
>   meaningful goal that excites and engages them.

I searched online dictionaries but I didn't find a good definition for"tippy top" especially one relates to the Text above.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> A sense of purpose. People want to feel as if their work matters, that
>   their contributions help achieve something really important. And
>   except for those **at the tippy top**, shareholder value isn’t a
>   meaningful goal that excites and engages them. They want to know that
>   they— and their organizations—are doing something big that matters to
>   other people.

https://hbr.org/2014/11/being-happy-at-work-matters

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tip-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a playful expression for "very top", or "top most", right at the top with nothing/no-one else further up. Also occurs as tip-top.

So, this is saying that shareholder value isn't a meaningful goal for people at a company, except those at the very top of the company, directors and presidents and vice presidents etc.

Answer (score 2):

tippy top is at the very top.

It is slightly childish language.

Those at the tippy top [of the economic spectrum]: the very richest people.

the Y sounds like IE: they are both pronounced the same way and sound kid-like or like something you would say to a child]:

[diminuitives in English](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-diminutive-suffixes-and-a-cute-little-prefix/)

16. -ie: Words with this suffix are from English (as in doggie), Scottish (for example, laddie), or Dutch (such as cookie), or are diminutives of personal names, as in Charlie. [or cutie, mine]
17. -y: This form, with doubling of the preceding letter, is seen both in diminutives of given names, such as Bobby and Patty, and in words like puppy and mommy. [or tippy, as in the OP's example: tippy top]